# How to compare two non stationary time series

Tags: time-series

I have searched a long time for comparison between non stationary time series but I'm a bit lost.

I have two time series (black and red below) and I want to prove statistically they are very similar.

This is the plot of my time series:

[image: Plot]

Could someone help me on the steps I need to perform please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare two series you can count correlation coefficients from them, I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, but can I use this with non-stationary time series ?

Comment: if the dependency from the and time base will be same in both signals, yes

Comment: Sorry to insist but could you explain me mathematically why this hypothesis are sufficient to use to correlation coefficient on non-stationary ts ?

Comment: ok, on the base level the correlation coefficient is the function that shows how similar two functions are, if they are both time dependent with the same function (and this function is continuous) we can simply tell that they are close to each other, and if the time dependent function is continuous if the result of it lays close to each other the arguments also, the only think we miss is the importance of data (for instance the noise * big time value may occure as huge difference) if the time function is known u can simply calculate as f^-1 and than we would get rid of this problem

Comment: Can it be useful to pre-whitening the series before using CCF ?